# How do you disable os_log_info and os_log_debug messages in Xcode console?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, terminal, console

Modern API for Logging is easy configurable in Terminal. However, Xcode seems to output all levels including INFO and DEBUG which is very annoying. Because most of the time you want to see only `os_log_error` and `NSLog` aka “something went wrong” and “this is important”.

So is there any way to display only particular levels in Xcode Console?

```
os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Info");
os_log_debug(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Debug");
os_log_error(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Error");
os_log_fault(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Fault");
os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Default");
NSLog(@"NSLog");
```

Current output:

```
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170807 Test[5681:2205834] Info
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170830 Test[5681:2205834] Debug
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170835 Test[5681:2205834] Error
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170839 Test[5681:2205834] Fault
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170860 Test[5681:2205834] Default
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170869 Test[5681:2205834] NSLog
```

Preferred output:

```
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170835 Test[5681:2205834] Error
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170839 Test[5681:2205834] Fault
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170860 Test[5681:2205834] Default
2016-12-14 15:37:00.170869 Test[5681:2205834] NSLog
```

Comment: try this OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

Comment: This will hide all messages but `NSLog` which is totally different from what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have used DTS and got the answer from an Apple engineer:

> The new unified logging system is a relatively recent addition and, alas, Xcode has not yet caught up with it.  If you'd like to see a future version of Xcode support log filtering, I encourage you to file an enhancement request describing your requirements.

So please duplicate `rdar://28288063`, the more requests the better. Thanks!

---

**Update:** As noted by Max below, you can modify visibility for custom logs:

```
os_log_t custom = os_log_create("com.acme.demo", "custom");
os_log_info(custom, "Info");
os_log_debug(custom, "Debug");
os_log_error(custom, "Error");
os_log_fault(custom, "Fault");
os_log(custom, "Default");
```

The following *Terminal* command will suppress “Info” and “Debug” strings in *Xcode*:

```
sudo log config --mode "level:default" --subsystem "com.acme.demo"
```

To reset system defaults:

```
sudo log config -reset --subsystem "com.acme.demo"
```

To check current status:

```
sudo log config --subsystem "com.acme.demo"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can switch debug-level in terminal:

```
$ sudo log config --mode "level:debug" --subsystem com.your_company.your_subsystem_name
```

To check your current level:

```
$ sudo log config --status --subsystem com.your_company.your_subsystem_name
Mode for 'com.your_company.your_subsystem_name'  DEBUG
```

For more information see [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the desired effect by setting the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `default` in the environment variables section of the scheme.

EDIT:
I see that this omits only the Debug log level. Info is still shown.