# Viewing os_log messages in device console

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, logging

I'm trying to get some logging out of my app through Unified Logging (os_log)

Here's the initialization of the log:

```
var osLog : OSLog = OSLog(subsystem: "com.test.testapp", category: "native-tester")
```

And here's how I use it:

```
os_log("iOS App initialized successfully!", log: osLog, type:.info)
```

When debugging the app normally, the logs appear properly on the console output, but when I look at the device console (Shown in the "Devices and Simulators" window) I don't see them at all.

[This article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) says that you should configure the system to enable the debug logs using

```
sudo log config --mode "level:debug" --subsystem com.test.testapp
```

But that didn't seem to make a difference. I'm guessing it's because I'm configuring the mac to view the logs, not the iPad.

How do I view the ipad / iphone logs from os_log in the device console?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The "Devices and Simulators" window only shows crash reports. Use the Console app or Terminal, via the `log --stream` command, to see live log output.

To see the device's live log messages via the Console app, either when running from Xcode or when running from the device directly:

- Open Console.app.
- Click on the device's name in the left side panel, under "Devices".
- Select *Action*, then *Include Info Messages* from the menu. If you are also using `.debug` level messages, make sure to select *Include Debug Messages* as well. (Without those items selected, the Console displays `.default`, `.fault`, and `.error` level messages only.)

If you still don't see the messages, try entering this Terminal command to configure the logging levels for your app:

```
sudo log config --subsystem com.test.testapp --mode level:debug
```

This turns on `.debug`-level logging for subsystem "com.test.testapp" (which includes `.info` and `.default` messages).

If you want to persist the messages, rather than the default of memory-only, turn on persistence for the three levels at the same time, like so:

```
sudo log config --subsystem com.test.testapp --mode level:debug,persist:debug
```

Regardless of any log settings, though, only crash reports will appear in the "Devices and Simulators" window.

Comment: There is also a radar that debug logs not showing up in the console app even though they are turned on if running on a simulator. Only showing up for real devices https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82736

Answer (score 24):

Another pitfall: If you have set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable` in your scheme, then you will not see any logs for your app in console.

You have to remove or uncheck that argument.

Comment: There is a question on how to disable logging where this variable is mentioned in a comment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142848/how-do-you-disable-os-log-info-and-os-log-debug-messages-in-xcode-console/45988511#comment69488204_41142848

Comment: This is what got me, this was disabled for Firebase Debug View to work, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In the console app, there are two options to include / hide debug and info messages:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Log types `.debug` and `.info` are by default memory only (not saved on disk) so it won't be visible on the device console.

Detailed info:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging?language=objc

Also here is pretty nice WWDC:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/

Comment: So what is the purpose of saving to memory only if it's not accessible? If it is accessible, how?

Answer (score 2):

Following screenshots could be helpful for reference-
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -3):

My os_log went missing after releasing an app to app store. I guess when I built the app for release, the debug option was turned off.

To enable the logging back... go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run Debug ... then check Debug executable.