# CAShow() not outputting to console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-audio

Trying to test the state of an AUGraph in a Swift 4.0 project.

```
var audioGraph: AUGraph? = nil

func createAUGraph() {

    NewAUGraph(&self.audioGraph)

    CAShow(UnsafeMutablePointer<AUGraph>(self.audioGraph!))
    CAShow(UnsafeMutablePointer(self.audioGraph!)) }
```

I am not seeing anything output to the Console, however.

I've stepped through the code and the AUGraph and AUNodes seem to be created and instantiated successfully..

Is this an indication the AUGraph does not exist ... Or have I used this AudioToolBox method incorrectly?

Comment: I did a quick check. I'm not getting an output either. The `self.audioGraph` does exist, at least it is not nil. Otherwise the ! would crash the app.

Comment: Thanks... I did not realize AUGraph was going to be deprecated in 2018. Perhaps that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. There's no output. Seemingly it's already muted in Swift 4.

```
import AudioToolbox

var audioGraph: AUGraph? = nil
var acd: UnsafePointer<AudioComponentDescription>? = nil
var outNode: UnsafeMutablePointer<AUNode>? = nil

func createAUGraph() {
    AUGraphAddNode(audioGraph!, acd!, outNode!)
    NewAUGraph(UnsafeMutablePointer<AUGraph>(audioGraph!))
    CAShow(UnsafeMutablePointer<AUGraph>(audioGraph!))
    CAShow(UnsafeMutablePointer(audioGraph!))
}

createAUGraph()
```

Comment: If the graph exists why then doesn't CAShow() have any output? There are older examples out there that show the result. I am questioning since AUGraph is set to be deprecated in 2018, that the output is somehow being muted.

Comment: Suppose, it's muted, and it will definitely be deprecated in iOS as stated in the WWDC talk.

Comment: I've tried many times adding and deleting nodes. But there's no output.

Answer (score 2):

`CAShow` prints to os_log.

You can see the log in the Console.app.
See this SO answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48229691/1960783

Alternatively you can use the other method `CAShowFile(void *inObject, FILE *inFile)` and use `stdout` for the file pointer to log directly to the Xcode console.

In Swift that would be:

`CAShowFile(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(graph), stdout)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the other method CAShowFile(void *inObject, FILE *inFile) and use stdout for the file pointer to log directly to the Xcode console